# string swapping works well with char ** but not with char *

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, swap

In this program I have swapped the first 2 names

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(char **,char **);
main()
{
 char *name[4]={"amol", "robin", "shanu" };
 swap(&name[0],&name[2]);
 printf("%s %s",name[0],name[2]);
}
void swap(char **x,char **y)
 {
 char *temp;
 temp=*x;
 *x=*y;
 *y=temp;
 }
```

This programs runs perfectly but when I use the `function swap(char *,char *)` it does not swap the address why? why I have to use pointer to pointer?

Comment: The fact that a string is a `char*` in C is probably adding to the confusion. Try implementing this with an array of integers first, then an array of pointers to integers, then an array of strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you understand that to swap integers you would have function like `swap(int *, int *)`

Similarly, When you want to swap strings which is `char *`. You would need function like `swap(char **, char **)`.

In such cases, you take their pointers and swap their content (otherwise values will not be swapped once function returns). For integer content, pointer is `int *` and in case of strings content is `char *` pointer to it is `char **`.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers (like all values) are passed by value.

If you use `swap(char * a,char * b)` and write `a = tmp;` this changes only the local variable `a` and not the original variable in the caller.

This simpler example also doesn't work as intended for the same reason:

```
void change(int x) {
    x = 0; // Only changes the local variable.
}

int main(void) { 
    int x = 0;
    change(x);       // This does not have any effect.
    printf("%d", x); // 0 is printed
    return 0; 
}
```

http://ideone.com/u7Prp

Answer (score 0):

`char *name[4]` is holding address of 3 string literals. If we want to swap, we have to pass the reference of the array where exactly the string literal's address is stored. That means we have to pass `name+0` and `name+2` or `&name[0]` and `&name[2]` to the swap function.

And also if you want to swap. you have to receive the address as `char **` and then we have to change the address of the string literals in the array.

If you receive it as `char *` and if you tries to change like `temp = x; x = y; y = temp`, that will be local change to the function `swap`. It will not reflect on the array `name`.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like this is what you are looking for:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(char *,char *);
main()
{
 char name[4][10]={"amol", "robin", "shanu" };
 swap(name[0],name[2]);
 printf("%s %s",name[0],name[2]);
}
void swap(char *x,char *y)
 {
 char *temp;
 temp=x;
 x=y;
 y=temp;
 }
```

The main difference is the declaration of name. In your version you declare an array of pointers so you have to dereference the entries as *name[0]. In the second version it declares an array of 'char arrays' or strings and each entry holds a string, not a pointer, so you can dereference the entries as name[0]. You will see the difference clearly if you use gdb and step through the code while using the print command.

Comment: This lets you use `function swap(char *,char *)` which is specified in your question.

Comment: This `swap()` does not swap anything on the caller side. In fact it is of NOOP, of no practical use.